# Not a valid regular expression

Tags: python, regex, django

I cannot understand why i'm getting this error:

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: `"^customers/(?P&lt;pk&gt;[0-9]+)$" is not a valid regular expression: unknown extension ?P& at position 12`

Here is my code of the file urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url 
from customers import views 

urlpatterns = [ 

  url(r'^customers/$', views.customer_list),
  url(r'^customers/(?P&lt;pk&gt;[0-9]+)$', views.customer_detail),
  url(r'^customers/age/(?P&lt;age&gt;[0-9]+)/$', views.customer_list_age),

]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `<` symbol instead of `&lt;` and also for `&gt;` it should be `>` (don't do html escape of url patterns), because `(?P<name>pattern)` refers to a named capturing group. ie. whatever the chars matched by the pattern inside a named capturing group will be accessed by it's name upon the match object.

```
urlpatterns = [ 

  url(r'^customers/$', views.customer_list),
  url(r'^customers/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.customer_detail),

]
```

So, here you could get the pk on views by accessing the view kwargs, ie. `kwrags['pk']`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/7grYoR/1)